# Read multiple XML files in one location and search for a string in those files and move the files to different location based on the string

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script.

Scenario:

XML files saved in c:\Temp\

I would like to search for a line in those XML files and every XML file has that line `<AccountNum>CU000043<AccountNum>`

Sample XML file:

```
-<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
-<Header>
<MessageId>{240ECE0A-19DC-4C0B-9B32-DED89888A1A5}</MessageId>
<Action>http://tempuri.org/shipment/read</Action>
</Header>
-<Body>
-<MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
-<shipment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/WHSShipmentASN">
<DocPurpose>Original</DocPurpose>
<SenderId>abc</SenderId>
<ValidAsOfDateTime>2018-06-22T20:08:25Z</ValidAsOfDateTime>
<ValidTimeStateType>AsOf</ValidTimeStateType>
-<shipmentTable class="entity">
<_DocumentHash>73ad5ddc457625bc0673e9d598c848cc</_DocumentHash>
<AccountNum>CU00131</AccountNum>
```

The 'AccountNum'value will be changed from time to time. What I want is, any file with a value *CU00145* or *CU00142* or *CU00144* or *CU00143* or *CU00070* must be moved to folder 'c:\temp\specific'. Other XML files, with value different from above, must be moved to 'c:\temp\others'.

My code sample:

```
$FileDirectory = "C:\Temp\lane\test";
$OutputPath  = "C:\Temp\lane\Specific";
$OutputPath2 = "C:\Temp\lane\Others";

Get-ChildItem $FileDirectory | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {

    $FilePath = $_.FullName
    $Header = Get-Content $FilePath  

    if ($Header | Select-String -Pattern 'CU00145, CU00142, CU00144, CU00143, CU00070') {
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath
    }
    else {
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath2
    }
}
```

I have worked on simple PowerShell script but this one is quite confusing for me. Any help will be much appreciated. I apologize if the information is not enough. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: please show us the code you've tried and some data samples

Comment: please check my updated post.

Comment: Please let me know because the updated code I have, move all the files to 'others' folder. It could not find the string for the customer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regexp to find the account number in your file with:

```
$Content = Get-Content $FilePath -Raw
$Content -match '\<AccountNum\>(?<AccountNum>[^<]+)\</AccountNum\>'
```

And then compare this account to a list with somthing like:

```
$FileDirectory    = "C:\Temp\test";
$SpecificAccounts = 'CU00145', 'CU00142', 'CU00144', 'CU00143', 'CU00070'
$OutputPath       = "C:\Temp\Specific";
$OutputPath2      = "C:\Temp\Others";

Get-ChildItem $FileDirectory -File | ForEach-Object {
    $FilePath = $_.FullName
    $Content = Get-Content $FilePath -Raw

    if ($Content -match '\<AccountNum\>(?<AccountNum>[^<]+)\</AccountNum\>') {
        if ($Matches['AccountNum'] -in $SpecificAccounts) {
            Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath
        }
        else {
            Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath2
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No account found in file $FilePath"
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPath2
    }
}
```